# CircuitBreaker in Apache Camel using Quarkus

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus, circuit-breaker

I am trying to use the CircuitBreaker component in Apache camel (version: 3.8.0) using Quarkus (version: 1.12.0.Final) and have included the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-microprofile-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My camel route code is as follows:

```
  //Some code above

  .circuitBreaker()              
    .faultToleranceConfiguration().timeoutEnabled(true).timeoutDuration(20000).end()
    .toD(nettyHttp("https://myurl"))
  .endCircuitBreaker()

  //Some code below;
```

I am getting the following error at compile time

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find camel-hystrix, camel-resilience4j or camel-microprofile-fault-tolerance on the classpath.
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.CircuitBreakerReifier.createProcessor(CircuitBreakerReifier.java:32)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:835)
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:576)
```

What am I doing wrong or rather how to incorporate CircuitBreaker using Camel-Quarkus?

Thanks,

Comment: As per the error you posted above, you need one of the following in your application classpath. 
1. amel-hystrix
2. camel-resilience4j
3. camel-microprofile-fault-tolerance

Comment: I have included microprofile dependency "camel-quarkus-microprofile-fault-tolerance" in my POM file, which includes "camel-microprofile-fault-tolerance".

Answer (score 0):

I am preparing a presentation for circuit breaker and quarkus.  I'm working with the 1.12.0.Final quarkus version too. I did not come across any problem. ı think your problem is maven . remove .m2 folder from your computer and run again .
`./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` if problem continues add this dependencies to your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-resilience4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and configure it like that

```
 from("timer:circuitTimer?delay=1000&period=1000")
           .circuitBreaker()
           .resilience4jConfiguration()
           .timeoutEnabled(true)
           .timeoutDuration(2000)
           .minimumNumberOfCalls(3)
           .waitDurationInOpenState(10)
           .end()
           .to("http://localhost:8081/book/1000")
            .onFallback()
            .transform().constant("Camel In Action")
            .end().end().log("${body}");
```

Comment: Thanks eray. I used your code in all my previous Apache-Camel, Springboot projects. I started using Quarkus framework and there it's recommended to use "microprofile-fault-tolerance", so I am trying to make it work. I got a solution for microprofile-fault-tolerance, which seems to be working. I have posted my solution above. If there is a better way do let me know. Your above code is definitely helpful for those who are trying CircuitBreaker with resilience4j.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made the "microprofile-fault-tolerance" work with Camel-Quarkus.
Include the microprofile fault toterance dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-microprofile-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Initialize the following class **FaultToleranceConfigurationDefinition** with your desired value.

```
FaultToleranceConfigurationDefinition faultToleranceConfig = new FaultToleranceConfigurationDefinition();
         faultToleranceConfig
                .timeoutEnabled(true)
                .timeoutDuration(30000)
                .successThreshold(10)
                .requestVolumeThreshold(4)
                .delay(5000)
                .failureRatio(50)
                .bulkheadEnabled(true)
                .bulkheadMaxConcurrentCalls(5)
                .bulkheadWaitingTaskQueue(8)
                .end();
```

How you initialize the instance of FaultToleranceConfigurationDefinition class is up to you (we can have it as Singleton class), then use the instance of the class as shown below.

```
   
//Some code above

  .circuitBreaker()              
    .faultToleranceConfiguration(faultToleranceConfig)
    .toD(nettyHttp("https://myurl"))
  .endCircuitBreaker()

  //Some code below;
```

If there is a better way, please let me know!!
Thanks